# Linux file leases - fcntl F_SETLEASE when file is already open somewhere in a conflicting way

Tags: linux

What happens if I'm trying to set a, say, *F_RDLCK* lease on a file that is already open for a writing somewhere else.

[fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) says

> A read lease can be placed only on a file descriptor that is opened
>   read-only.

Does it mean it should be open read-only system-wise and otherwise [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) call will fail with, presumingly *EACCES*? If so, is there any other way to wait for the lease to be possible other than using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) (*IN_CLOSE_WRITE*)?

Answer (score 1):

This call:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETLEASE, F_RDLCK)
```

will fail with `EAGAIN` ("Resource temporarily unavailable") if underlying file is currently opened for writing in *any* process.

It corresponds to description in manual page:

> **EACCES or EAGAIN**
>
> Operation is prohibited by locks held by other processes.

If caller itself opened `fd` for writing (i.e. *not* with `O_RDONLY` flag), it's just a special case of this rule and `fcntl()` also returns `EAGAIN`.